# Splash screen error size. IOS Xcode 7.1

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am currently having a weird error on my iPhone application splash screen display.I use images.xcassets for my splash screens. Everything works fine except for my iPhone 6 splash screen. For some reason, it seems that the iPhone 6 (phone and simulator) uses the iPhone 4s splash screen instead of the iPhone 6 splash screen.. Yet, the iPhone 6s (phone and simulator) uses the correct iPhone 6 splash screen.

I am currently using xcode 7.1

here are the name and sizes of my splash screens (I only use portrait):

```
iPhone4s: "Default.png" (640x960)
iPhone5: "Default-568h@2x.png" (640x1136)
iPhone6: "Default-667h@2x.png" (750x1334)
iPhone6plus: "Default-736@3x.png" (1242x2208)
```

Do you guys know if this is an xcode bug or know what could be the issue. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Keep it simple. Use image assets for the launch images. Better yet, use a launch screen.

Comment: but If i use a launch screen, how can I switch the image resolution for different devices? For example, if I use my iphone 6 image for my launch screen, won't it look out of proportion on the iPhone 4s?

Comment: The whole point of using a launch screen is that the screen is fit to the current device. Of course this assumes you are using launch images that aren't just fancy graphic splash screens and are actually simplified renditions of your root view controller like they are supposed to be.